# Spark Structured Streaming - Spike in input rate decreases batch duration

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am encountering something that on the first glance of Spark Streaming novice seems counter-intuitive:

**when Spark Structured Streaming starts processing more data, it's batch duration decreases**

This is probably not the most accurate picture, but I saw much clearer pattern..
[image]

I probably need an explanation of **what exactly is the batch duration** - my understanding is that it represents the the number of seconds it takes Spark to process the streaming's mini-batch.

Next, I need clarification on **how Spark triggers the processing of the mini-batch** - whether it's based on the amount of data in the batch or time intervals...

**EDIT**
The code is following. There is quite a lot of "heavy" operations (joins, dropDuplicates, filtering with HOF, udfs, ...). Sink and Source are both Azure Eventhubs

```
# [CONFIGS]
ehConfig = {
'eventhubs.startingPosition': '{"offset": "@latest", "enqueuedTime": null, 'isInclusive': true,'seqNo': -1}',
'eventhubs.maxEventsPerTrigger': 300,
'eventhubs.connectionString'='XXX'}

ehOutputConfig = {
'eventhubs.connectionString'='YYY' ,   
"checkpointLocation": "azure_blob_storage/ABCABC"
}

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 3)

# [FUNCS]
@udf(TimestampType())
def udf_current_timestamp():
  return datetime.now()

#-----------#
# STREAMING # 
#-----------#

# [STREAM INPUT]
df_stream_input = spark.readStream.format("eventhubs").options(**_ehConfig).load()

# [ASSEMBLY THE DATAFRAME]
df_joined = (df_stream_input
             .withColumn("InputProcessingStarted", current_timestamp().cast("long"))

             # Decode body
             .withColumn("body_decoded", from_json(col("body").cast("string"), schema=_config))

             # Join customer 
             .join(df_batch, ['CUSTOMER_ID'], 'inner')

             # Filtering
             .filter(expr('body_decoded.status NOT IN (0, 4, 32)'))
             .filter(expr('EXISTS(body_decoded.items, item -> item.ID IN (1, 2, 7))'))

             # Deduplication
             .withWatermark('enqueuedTime', '1 day') 
             .dropDuplicates(['CUSTOMER_ID', 'ItemID']) 

             # Join with lookup table
             .join(broadcast(df_lookup), ['OrderType'], 'left') 

             # UDF
             .withColumn('AssembleTimestamp', udf_current_timestamp())

             # Assemble struct 
             .withColumn('body_struct', struct('OrderType', 'OrderID', 'Price', 'StockPile'))

 # [STREAM OUTPUT]
(df_joined
 .select(to_json('body_struct').alias('body'))
 .writeStream
 .format("eventhubs")
 .options(**_ehOutputConfig)
 .trigger(processingTime='2 seconds')
 .start())
```

Comment: Can you describe the query's write-path? The trigger, the sink, and the output mode. What is the streaming query doing? Is it stateless or stateful? Any aggregations or joins?

Comment: Hi @JacekLaskowski, I added the query code. There is quite a lot of going on - the query contains 2 joins, dropDuplicates, parsing and assembling structs, filtering, udf etc.. But in the end, the query is just row-by-row processing => output mode is simple append.

Comment: Addition: we run it on two 8GB, 2 CPU nodes (one is driver, one is worker)

Comment: Can you include `streamingQuery.explain` in your question?

Comment: BTW How did you get the metrics and the charts?

Answer (score 1):

In Spark structured streaming, it triggers new batch as soon as previous batch has finished processing unless you specify trigger option.

In earlier version of Spark with Spark Streaming, we could specify the batch duration of let's say 5 seconds. In that case, it will trigger micro-batch every 5 seconds and process the data that has arrived in last 5 seconds. In case of kafka, it will get data that hasn't been committed.